# mongodb 3.0 wiredtiger unexpected shutdown

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04, wiredtiger

I am having an expected shutdown of mongodb 3.0 with wiredtiger storage engine with following log. This happens

```
2015-03-08T13:28:14.026-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835694:25835][10671:0x7fc3ce4d0700], log-server: /home/main/mongo/database/journal: opendir: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:14.026-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835694:26975][10671:0x7fc3ce4d0700], log-server: dirlist journal prefix WiredTigerPreplog: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:14.027-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835694:27078][10671:0x7fc3ce4d0700], log-server: log pre-alloc server error: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:14.027-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835694:27187][10671:0x7fc3ce4d0700], log-server: log server error: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:53.023-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835733:23042][10671:0x7fc3cdccf700], file:WiredTiger.wt, session.checkpoint: /home/main/mongo/database/WiredTiger.turtle.set: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:53.023-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (2) [1425835733:23499][10671:0x7fc3cdccf700], checkpoint-server: checkpoint server error: No such file or directory
2015-03-08T13:28:53.024-0400 E STORAGE  WiredTiger (-31804) [1425835733:24674][10671:0x7fc3cdccf700], checkpoint-server: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2015-03-08T13:28:53.024-0400 I -        Fatal Assertion 28558
2015-03-08T13:28:53.051-0400 I CONTROL  
 0xf3f529 0xedfd81 0xec5191 0xd561f6 0x1368530 0x13687f5 0x1368c91 0x12ffa73 0x7fc3d1dcf182 0x7fc3d089847d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B3F529"},{"b":"400000","o":"ADFD81"},{"b":"400000","o":"AC5191"},{"b":"400000","o":"9561F6"},{"b":"400000","o":"F68530"},{"b":"400000","o":"F687F5"},{"b":"400000","o":"F68C91"},{"b":"400000","o":"EFFA73"},{"b":"7FC3D1DC7000","o":"8182"},{"b":"7FC3D079E000","o":"FA47D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.0", "gitVersion" : "a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.8.0-38-generic", "version" : "#56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:22:48 UTC 2014", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "5F365548FE8312E027817D98FEECA3A18F0F60FB" }, { "b" : "7FFFA51F6000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CB7F92627725102C17126BB9F42F9EB0E15D19D7" }, { "b" : "7FC3D1DC7000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9318E8AF0BFBE444731BB0461202EF57F7C39542" }, { "b" : "7FC3D1B69000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF43D0947510134A8A494063A3C1CF3CEBB27791" }, { "b" : "7FC3D178F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "379F80D2768BA6A21F52781895EE9F47B34A0A85" }, { "b" : "7FC3D1587000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92FCF41EFE012D6186E31A59AD05BDBB487769AB" }, { "b" : "7FC3D1383000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C1AE4CB7195D337A77A3C689051DABAA3980CA0C" }, { "b" : "7FC3D107F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "19EFDDAB11B3BF5C71570078C59F91CF6592CE9E" }, { "b" : "7FC3D0D79000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D76B71E905CB867B27CEF230FCB20F01A3178F5" }, { "b" : "7FC3D0B63000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D0AA71411580EE6C08809695C3984769F25725B" }, { "b" : "7FC3D079E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "30C94DC66A1FE95180C3D68D2B89E576D5AE213C" }, { "b" : "7FC3D1FE5000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9F00581AB3C73E3AEA35995A0C50D24D59A01D47" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf3f529]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0xedfd81]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x61) [0xec5191]
 mongod(+0x9561F6) [0xd561f6]
 mongod(+0xF68530) [0x1368530]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x95) [0x13687f5]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x21) [0x1368c91]
 mongod(+0xEFFA73) [0x12ffa73]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7fc3d1dcf182]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fc3d089847d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-03-08T13:28:53.051-0400 I -        

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I started it manually with manually downloaded mongodb binaries with `mongod --config mongodb.conf`. User executing this command has full access to the database folder. Configuration file follows

```
dbpath=/home/main/mongo/database
logpath=/home/main/mongo/mongolog/log
logappend=true
storageEngine = wiredTiger
fork = true
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Looks like the directories don't exist or there's a permissions issue preventing the mongod process from accessing them.

Comment: I have proper permissions given to the directories. When I exit from the ssh session after starting the mongodb daemon (--fork), it shuts down in a few minutes. But if the ssh session is running, the mongodb daemon keeps running as well.

Comment: " /home/main/mongo/database/WiredTiger.turtle.set: No such file or directory" clearly indicates there is a file system issue.